# Add text to fixed preloader

Tags: css, ajax, text, loader

I'm trying to add a loader (spinner gif + text) that is fixed in the middle of the browser window while waiting for an AJAX response. So far I managed to position my gif correctly, but I have a bit of a trouble when it comes to anchoring the text to the loader.

CSS:

```
.preloader-bg { 
    background: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.3); 
    display: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    z-index: 10; 
}

#preloader { 
    background-image: url(images/preloader.gif); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    position: fixed; 
    display: block; 
    left : 0; 
    bottom : 0; 
    right : 0; 
    top : 0; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="preloader-bg">
    <div id="preloader">
    </div>
</div>
```

I show and hide the preloader using jquery during ajax calls. I want to anchor the text to the bottom part of the loader. I'm a begginner when it comes to designing layouts and css so any tips would be huge. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.preloader-bg { 
    background: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.3); 
   /*  display: none;  */
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    z-index: 10; 
}

#preloader { 
    background-image: url(http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    position: fixed; 
    display: block;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#preloader p{
   position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 50%;
  /* top:0; */
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: -5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="preloader-bg">
    <div id="preloader">
   <p>text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4nxq9wrm/)

Comment: A fixed element inside a absolute positioned wrapper doesn't make any sense. Your `margin-bottom:-5em` is bad practice as well. *(I know it's a mistake OP did, but you would not have to copy it.)* As soon as the font-size would be increased at one of this hierarchical elements, the relative margin would increase as well. When you start adding multi-line text or further elements, it'd wander further up and overlap your loader image. ...

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/kvduL2nj/

**HTML**

```
<div class="preloader-wrapper">
    <div class="preloader">
       Loading...<br/>
       And whatever you want to have here.
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.preloader-wrapper { 
    background: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.3); 
    width: 100%; height: 100%; 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}

.preloader-wrapper > .preloader { 
    background: transparent url(https://graphiclineweb.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/ajaxloader.gif?w=604) no-repeat center top;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 128px; /* image-width of loader */
    min-height: 128px; /* image-height of loader */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding-top: 148px; /* 128px image-height of loader + 20px margin */
    text-align: center;
}
```

The *preloader-wrapper* is the one that should be `position:fixed`. Inside the actual *preloader* should be horizontally and vertically centered. The rest is commented in the CSS.